# Is it possible for a set to contain non-mathematical objects?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, philosophy

This might be a somewhat philosophical question and perhaps I even have a wrong understanding of what I write as a premise, so I am sorry if that is the case. A set is usually any collection of objects, such as the natural numbers $1,2,3,$ $\{1,2,3\}$. In this case, I have mathematical objects, namely numbers. As far as I know, numbers are assumed to exist as objects and we are just denoting them with symbols. Therefore an object of the natural numbers should be anything that exists in this pre-existing set that is thought of as the natural numbers. This somewhat clarifies what is meant with a natural number as an object. However, I now wondered what happens when I "mix" sets up, with non-mathematical expressions, such as $$\{1,A,\mathrm{Car}\}$$ consisting of the natural number $1$, the letter $A$ and the word "Car" or $$\{A,B,C\}$$ consisting of the letters $A,B,C$.

I would've initially said that they are sets, however, I would not know what the underlying objects should even be, except for the "explanation" of $1$ from the beginning. I know however that especially sets such as $\{A,B,C\}$ are often used when functions are taught, to create easy (injective/surjective/bijective) functions from a small set to another. Are they really considered to be sets though, despite them not being mathematical objects? If one is really strict and works in formal set theory, then one could model them to be sets, I suppose, but I rather ask from a more "everyday mathematics" perspective.

Comment: A set can contain everything, but mathematicians usually only work with sets containing only mathematical objects including exotics like hyperreal numbers. Every non-empty set with countable many objects (in daily life we almost always only have finite sets) can be bijectively mapped to {$1,\cdots ,n$} or to $\mathbb N$ anyway.

Comment: @Peter If that is the case, would there be a difference between the sets $\{\alpha\}$ and $\{A\}$? Would one say that $\alpha$ is a symbol for the object of a greek letter and $A$ for a letter of the Latin alphabet? If this is the difference, would there still be a difference if I assumed that the symbols $A$ and $\alpha$ have not been used for anything before and were completely new symbols? Or would the set then be a collection of symbols, if there is no underlying "object-structure"?

Comment: Of course those sets are still different since they do not contain the same elements. Letters are still common because every letter can be used as a variable . We often have something like {$x\in\mathbb N|x>10$} , but a collection of letters is usually not used in mathematics.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much! Just to make sure I understand you correctly, assuming that the symbols have no other meaning, the sets are different because they are different symbols, right? I could define $\alpha$ as well as $A$ to be the natural number $1$, which would make the sets equal. Thus I need to assume that they are not already symbols for anything.

Comment: If the elements are just written down ,seperated by commas , we consider different symbols to be different although we can assign the same value to them.

Comment: In mathematics? No. Since mathematics only studies mathematical objects. Not in mathematics? That's none of the business of mathematical sets.

Comment: @Peter But wouldn't $\{alpha,A\}=\{A\}=\{\alpha\}$ if $\alpha=A$? Why would we consider them as different?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your comment. So you are saying that without more context $\{A,B,C\}$ wouldn't be a set as, say, letters of the alphabet? Isnt that contradicting to what has been said here as an answer/comments?

Comment: The below answer summarizes the situation excellent.

Comment: Usually , a symbol in a set is not identified with the value we might have assigned to it. I agree with the example given under the below answer with the days.

Answer (score 2):

A *set* is a collection of *elements* or *objects* (these are synonyms).

Objects within a sets should have *meaning within a context*. $A$, as an element of a set, doesn't have any meaning *without any further context*.

If however, you defined $A$ to be a specific cat that your friend Dave owns, then $A$ is actually referencing something, and now $\ \{A\},\ $ can be thought of as a set whose only object contained in it references that cat. But unless we give $A$ some reference like this, $A$ and therefore $\ \{A\}\ $ have no meaning.

I'm not saying the object has to be an object in the real world. If we define $A=0,$ where $0$ is a member of the integers, and we have previously defined the integers, then the set $\ \{A\}\ $ has meaning within a context and this can usefully be conveyed to someone else.

But $\ \{A\},\ $ where $A$ has not been defined, means a set that contains something, but we don't know what that something is, so it's a bit meaningless and lacks context for it to be useful or to convey any meaning within a context at all.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't one interpret a "default value" as a symbol? I don't know if this is common, but that way $\{A\}$ would make sense in every case, even though it might not be an interesting set.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. A standard example when starting out with sets is: $X= $ Days of the Week = $\{ $ Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday $ \}$. And then ask, "Is Monday $\in\ X?$ " to which the answer is obviously yes. I guess you could define a set $Y = \{ A \}\ $ and then ask, "Is $A$ in the set $X$ ? to which the answer again, is obviously yes. But this is about as useful as this example becomes. So in my opinion, your question is not very interesting, and is kind of pedantic (no offence).

Comment: It for sure is pedantic, so I don't feel offended at all. What I mean by that is just that the set $\{A\}$ is the collection of the symbol $A$. Thus $A$ is in the set, since it is the same symbol, whereas $a$ or $b$ would not. This will be useless in probably all cases, I just wanted to make sure if this is the correct way this works.

Comment: You're correct that $A$ is in the set whereas $a$ and $b$ are not.

Comment: @MaxH: You keep confusing yourself about this issue because you failed to distinguish between symbols and their interpretation. "MaxH" is a string with 4 characters. MaxH is a user on Math SE. They are different. "A" a string with 1 character, and absolutely nothing else. If in some piece of mathematics you define $A = 2$, that has absolutely nothing to do with "A".

Comment: @AdamRubinson: You didn't address MaxH's comment correctly, although your post itself is completely correct.

Comment: @user21820 I answered this a while ago and bothered to revisit it. Feel free to post your own answer if you think it would help the OP...

Comment: I think that my first comment suffices to help the asker. I posted my second comment only to explain to you that you missed the asker's misconception, while making clear that I had no objection to your post itself. That's all, and thanks for your reply!